# Apache QPID queue size and count

Tags: apache, jms, qpid

I have a qpid queue with this parameters:
**bus-sync-queue --durable --file-size=48 --file-count=64**

I want to put to this queue **1 000 000** messages. Each message is just a string with **12** characters. (002000333222, 002000342678 and so on). What values I must set to config --file-size=**X** --file-count=**Y** to able to fit all messages to queue?

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a big overhead on single persistent message, in you case one message will require at least 128 bytes of storage. You should rethink your design, either decrease expected number of no-acknowledged messages or use different approach.